# Trouble file StringProperty subtype FILE_PATH

Tags: python, scripting, file-browser

I have a `StringProperty(subtype="FILE_PATH)` and I am trying to make it so the user selects a folder and then a file is saved out to the location, but the filepath comes out looking really funky.

The folder selected is `D:\Pictures`, what the `StringProperty` shows is `//..\..\`. What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`//` indicates a relative path in Blender.

Make sure you untick **Relative Path** in the *Accept* panel of the file browser to make it an absolute path.

Or you can convert a relative path to a absolute path using the built in method `bpy.path.abspath(path)`

Comment: is there a way to make it an absolute path automatically?

Comment: You can globally disable relative paths: *User Preferences > File > Relative Paths*, it's the first checkbox below the label **Save & Load**.