# How do I display the absolute file (or directory) path in the UI

Tags: python, scripting, file-browser

I've seen a number of answers on here and other places that if I have a file path in Blender, I can use `bpy.path.abspath(file_path)` and get the absolute path to a file or directory. My problem is that I have a StringProperty with `subtype = 'DIR_PATH'` set and I'm having problems with what it displays:

[image]

The path is set to `/User/<my_name>/Documents/Dev/3DGraphics/3DExperiments`, however notice only two slashes show. The StringProperty is showing a path relative to the current file in Blender. When I select another directory, it still gives me a relative path.

I'm using this structure:

```
class BluePrinterData(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    status: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="status",
        default="Waiting for Cameras to be Added"
        )
    project_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="project_name"
        )
    save_directory: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = "",
        description = "Output Directory",
        default = '',
        maxlen = 1024,
        subtype = 'DIR_PATH'
        )
    file_format: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = 'File Output Format',
        description = 'File format for saving images',
        items = {('png', 'PNG', 'Save as PNG'),
                 ('pdf', 'PDF', 'Save as PDF'),
                 ('bmp', 'BMP', 'Save as BMP'),
                 ('tiff', 'TIFF', 'Save as TIFF')},
        default = 'png'
        )
```

Note the 3rd property down, `save_directory`, is the one I'm talking about and I've set the subtype as needed.

I've tried adding an `if` statement to change the path to absolute if it isn't, but that doesn't make a difference.

The one thing I'm trying to do here is make sure that instead of seeing the relative path in the StringProperty, I see the absolute path.

I've looked over API docs, but I can't find what I have to change to display an absolute path.

(Again, please note I know when I need that absolute path in Python, I can convert - but I can't find a way to convert what the StringProperty with the `subtype = 'DIR_PATH'` to show the absolute path.)

Comment: TLDR; In the file dialog hit `N` and untick *Relative* (allows the user to decide). Exactly the same question: [How can I get the full path of the selected file from the file explorer with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195938/how-can-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-selected-file-from-the-file-explorer-with-pyt), Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12152/absolute-path-of-files-in-blender-with-python

Comment: @brockmann: I was so busy going over the code in that answer that I didn't see the part about using 'N' while using the file browser. Also, I played around and changed `default='` to `default='//'` and that changed it to display the absolute path, but I don't know why. CodeManX describes that, but I still don't get why the double-slash overrides and starts with an absolute path.

Comment: *"//" prefix is a Blender specific identifier for the current blend file.*: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6846/31447 You do not have to set any default path, just let the user decide whether the path should be absolute or relative as explained in my answer (second comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to display the *absolute path* nor convert it or set some default path because the user can set it to *absolute* or *relative* in the *File Browser* (<kbd>N</kbd>) which is actually a nice feature. If you really need an absolute path representation at some point, just call [`bpy.path.abspath(path)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.path.html#bpy.path.abspath) as explained in [How can I get the full path of the selected file from the file explorer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195938/how-can-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-selected-file-from-the-file-explorer/195971#195971).

[image]

**Further reading**

- [How can I get the full path of the selected file from the file explorer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/195971/31447) (potential duplicate)
- [Trouble file StringProperty subtype FILE_PATH](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23258/trouble-file-stringproperty-subtype-file-path) (potential duplicate)